# How to update a function in a mixin that was defined outside a return?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, gallery

In `lib/web/mage/gallery/gallery.js L:22` I want to update this function:

```
var getMainImageIndex = function (data) {
            var mainIndex;

            if (_.every(data, function (item) {
                    return _.isObject(item);
                })
            ) {
                mainIndex = _.findIndex(data, function (item) {
                    return item.isMain;
                });
            }

            return mainIndex > 0 ? mainIndex : 0;
        },
```

So I created a mixin `gallery-mixin.js` :

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';
    alert("gallery outside")

    var mixin = {
        /**
         *
         * @param {Column} elem
         */
        getMainImageIndex: function (data) {
            alert('test');
            var imageIndex = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (_.isObject(data[i]) && data[i].type === "image") {
                    imageIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return imageIndex >= 0 ? imageIndex : 0;
        }
    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../columns returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive
    };
});
```

This in fact does trigger the `alert("gallery outside")`, so the require-config.js configuration is correct, but does not trigger the alert in the function I want to override (`getMainImageIndex`). In the source file it seems to be defined outside of the return as a variable (not a method). I feel that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'fotorama/fotorama',
    'underscore',
    'matchMedia',
    'mage/template',
    'text!mage/gallery/gallery.html',
    'uiClass',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, fotorama, _, mediaCheck, template, galleryTpl, Class, $t) {
    'use strict';

    function getMainImageIndex(data) {
        var imageIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (_.isObject(data[i]) && data[i].type === "image") {
                imageIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return imageIndex >= 0 ? imageIndex : 0;
    }

    var mixin = {
        /**
         *
         * @param {Column} elem
         */


        initGallery: function () {
            var breakpoints = {},
                settings = this.settings,
                config = this.config,
                tpl = template(galleryTpl, {
                    next: $t('Next'),
                    previous: $t('Previous')
                }),
                mainImageIndex,
                $element = settings.$element,
                $fotoramaElement,
                $fotoramaStage;

            if (settings.breakpoints) {
                _.each(_.values(settings.breakpoints), function (breakpoint) {
                    var conditions;

                    _.each(_.pairs(breakpoint.conditions), function (pair) {
                        conditions = conditions ? conditions + ' and (' + pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1] + ')' :
                        '(' + pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1] + ')';
                    });
                    breakpoints[conditions] = breakpoint.options;
                });
                settings.breakpoints = breakpoints;
            }

            _.extend(config, config.options,
                {
                    options: undefined,
                    click: false,
                    breakpoints: null
                }
            );
            settings.currentConfig = config;

            $element
                .css('min-height', settings.$element.height())
                .append(tpl);

            $fotoramaElement = $element.find('[data-gallery-role="gallery"]');

            $fotoramaStage = $fotoramaElement.find('.fotorama__stage');
            $fotoramaStage.css('position', 'absolute');

            $fotoramaElement.fotorama(config);
            $fotoramaElement.find('.fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama__active')
                    .one('f:load', function () {
                        // Remove placeholder when main gallery image loads.
                        $element.find('.gallery-placeholder__image').remove();
                        $element
                            .removeClass('_block-content-loading')
                            .css('min-height', '');

                        $fotoramaStage.css('position', '');
                    });
            settings.$elementF = $fotoramaElement;
            settings.fotoramaApi = $fotoramaElement.data('fotorama');

            $.extend(true, config, this.startConfig);

            mainImageIndex = getMainImageIndex(config.data);

            if (mainImageIndex) {
                this.settings.fotoramaApi.show({
                    index: mainImageIndex,
                    time: 0
                });
            }
        }
    };

    return function (target) { // target == Result that Magento_Ui/.../columns returns.
        return target.extend(mixin); // new result that all other modules receive
    };
});
```

So I created the variation of the `getMainImageIndex` function outside of the mixin, and copied the entire `initGallery` method into the mixin. In the method I then refer to my newly created function.

Probably not the best solution (quite verbose), but I did not know how else to do it.